# wc_mail in foreach loop is sending only the first email

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-mail

I'm trying to send emails in a foreach loop from a db query and all fine here, but i need to send emails fo each id on the table and only works once, but is not showing any error, seems all fine!. Here is the code:

```php
        public function praga_emails(){

            global $wpdb;
            // $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wpbu_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'slzexploore_tbook_order' AND `meta_value` = '". $order_id ."' ORDER BY wpbu_postmeta.post_id", ARRAY_A ); 

            $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wpbu_praga_user_notice`", ARRAY_A ); 
            $errors = array();

            if ( $wpdb->num_rows !== 0 ) {

                foreach ($results as $result) { 

                    $send = $this->praga_emails_after_order( $result['tbook'] ); 

                    if ( !$send ) {
                        $errors[] = $result['tbook'];
                    }

                }

            }  

            echo json_encode( [ 'code' => 1, 'errors' => $errors ] );
            wp_die();

    } 

    public function praga_emails_after_order( $reservacion_id = null ){

        global $wpdb;

        if ( $reservacion_id === null ) {
            return false;
        }

                    $reservacion = get_post( $reservacion_id, ARRAY_A );
                    $reservacion_meta = get_post_meta( $reservacion_id );

                    $tour_id = get_post_meta( $reservacion_id, 'slzexploore_tbook_tour', true );
                    $tour = get_post( $tour_id, ARRAY_A ); 

                    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
                    $order = new WC_Order( $reservacion_meta['slzexploore_tbook_order'][0] );
                    $order_id = $order->get_id();

                    // -------- Confirm -----------
                    ob_start();
                        include_once( CUSTOM_PRAGA_DIR . '/templates/email-confirm.php');
                    $content = ob_get_contents(); 
                    ob_end_clean();
                    ob_end_flush(); 

                    //format the email
                    $recipient = $order->get_billing_email(); 
                    $subject = esc_html__('Tu Reserva ha sido confirmada:', 'custom-praga') . ' ' . get_post_meta( $tour_id, 'slzexploore_tour_display_title', true); 

                    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
                    //send the email through wordpress
                    wc_mail( $recipient, $subject, $content, $headers ); 


                    // -------- Admin -----------

                    ob_start();
                        include_once( CUSTOM_PRAGA_DIR . '/templates/email-admin.php');
                    $admin_content = ob_get_contents(); 
                    ob_end_clean();
                    ob_end_flush(); 

                    //format the email
                    $admin_recipient = Redux::getOption('custom_praga', 'email-admin'); 
                    $admin_subject = esc_html__('Nueva Reserva:', 'custom-praga') . ' ' . get_post_meta( $tour_id, 'slzexploore_tour_display_title', true); 

                    $admin_headers = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
                    //send the email through wordpress
                    wc_mail( $admin_recipient, $admin_subject, $admin_content, $admin_headers );

                    // -------- Proveedor -----------

                    // DATE
                    $sqldate = get_post_meta( $reservacion_id, "slzexploore_tbook_tour_date", true );
                    // BEGIN EMAIL
                    ob_start();
                      $euro = get_post_meta( $reservacion_id, 'slzexploore_tbook_deposit_amount', true );
                      $tasa = Redux::getOption('custom_praga', 'exchange-rate');
                      $price = $euro * $tasa; 
                      include_once( CUSTOM_PRAGA_DIR . '/templates/email-proveedor.php');
                    $proveedor_content = ob_get_contents(); 
                    ob_end_clean();
                    ob_end_flush();

                    //format the email 
                    $terms_p = get_the_terms( $tour_id, 'proveedor' ); 
                    $proveedor_recipient = get_term_meta( $terms_p[0]->term_id, 'correo', true ); 
                    // $proveedor_recipient = 'reandimo23@gmail.com';
                    $proveedor_subject = esc_html__('Reserva', 'custom-praga'); 

                    $proveedor_headers = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
                    //send the email through wordpress
                    wc_mail( $proveedor_recipient, $proveedor_subject, $proveedor_content, $proveedor_headers );

                    //Prevent multiple emails
                    $wpdb->delete( 'wpbu_praga_user_notice', array( 'tbook' => $reservacion_id ) );

                    return true;


    }
```

`praga_emails` is an ajax function, and `praga_emails_after_order` sends 3 emails with 3 different templates. This is working only once, any thoughts ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You use `include_once` in `praga_emails_after_order()` method therefore files (templates: *email-confirm.php*, *email-admin.php*, *email-proveedor.php*) will be included only in the first iteration.

Try to use `include` instead of `include_once`, it's possible that next emails are not sent because of empty content.